# Remove Unorder Number From Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

**i Have Data Like this**

> 9372127603 
> 9372130412  
> 9372140   
> 9372175041 
> 937218 
> 9372190908 
> 9372191764

**i need output like**

> 9372127603 
> 9372130412  
> 9372175041  
> 9372190908  
> 9372191764

**what i do to achieve this in sublime text ?**

Comment: Okay great. Just make it your output. You don't even need to process anything. Just set it as your output. Why are you even asking how to achieve it? It's just a simple matter of a defined output. Unless you are trying to process the input to get this? But we don't know that because you haven't said so. We have no indication of **how** you want to get this output. Please read [ask] and provide a full [mre]. We at least need to know what you are trying to do with the text and not just your input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via regex Find and Replace. Open **`Find → Replace…`**, make sure the regex option is on, enter `^\d{1,9}\n` into the **`Find:`** field, and make sure the **`Replace:`** field is empty:

[image: Full window before replace]

Explanation:

```regex
^       beginning of line
\d      any digit
{1,9}   match preceding between 1 and 9 times, inclusive
\n      newline character
```

[test at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uobgOn/1)

Once you've done that, hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> and any numbers less than 10 digits long will be removed:

[image: after replace]